# How to append data in ng-repeat scope from outside in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue with AngularJS `ng-view` and `ng-repeat`, and I believe it has to do with the way I handle the `scope`. I use `ng-repeat` to show a list of items present in an array. And a button that is outside the `ng-repeat` `scope` on `ng-click` updates the array. But some how I am not able to get this feature working. Here is a sample of my code:

```
<!-- home.html partial -->
<h1>Home view</h1>
<div>
  <ul ng-repeat="p in posts.data">
    <li>{{p.title}}</li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" ng-click="updatePosts(5)">More</a>
</div>
```

Here is the controller that is bound to this partial file:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      controller: 'testController',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});

app.controller('testController', 
  [
    '$scope', 
    function ($scope) 
    {
      $scope.posts = {
        data : []
      };
      $scope.getPosts = function(count)
      {
        for(i =0; i<count; ++i)
        {
          $scope.posts.data.push({title : "Title-"+i})
        }
      }
      $scope.updatePosts = function(count)
      {
        var offset = $scope.posts.data.length;
        var data = [];
        for(i =offset; i<offset+count; ++i)
        {
          data.push({title : "Title-"+i});
        }
        $scope.posts.data = $scope.posts.data.concat(data)
      }
      $scope.getPosts(5);
    }
  ]
);
```

The feature that I want is when one clicks "More" link on the main page, the controller should get little snippets of code and update the view with more data. For instance, I would expect the view to go from (1)  to (2) on clicking "More". But I always end up with just (1) no matter what.

---

(1)

**Home View**

- Title-0
- Title-1
- Title-2
- Title-3
- Title-4

More

(2)

**Home View**

- Title-0
- Title-1
- Title-2
- Title-3
- Title-4
- Title-5
- Title-6
- Title-7
- Title-8
- Title-9

More

I also have the above example setup in Plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yKxk8CVNKrp4UUFtThUX)

** update**
I tried the same code without using `ng-view` and the code works exactly as expected. So I am sure that the problem that I am encountering has to do with my usage of `ng-view`. An example in Pnkr setup without using `ng-view` is shown [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/b1QMdI1jfKxrGr42J29K)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is (almost) correct.

The only problem is that `<a href="#" ...` causes a redirection to the default view, thus re-instantiating your controller (and resetting the number of posts to 5).

In Angular, if you want to have an `<a>` element that gets styled like an `<a>`, but does nothing on click by default, use `href=""`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I completely missed this. Could you help me understand why the `<a href="#" ..` is not a problem when I don't use `ng-view`.

Comment: @goutham it's not an issue without `ng-view` because there is no routing involved

Answer (score 1):

Ok what is actually happening is with the `#` href the click default is not being prevented and the view is refreshing since the route represented by `#` alone doesn't exist

You can prove this by logging to console from your `getPosts` function.

Several ways around it are:

- remove href and set css `cursor:pointer` if you want it to respond the same
- leave the href as it is and pass `$event` into the function as argument and use `$event.preventDefault()`
- change href to empty string

**[Here's a working version without href](http://plnkr.co/edit/rEAqzfQGAzGPsUnc8fVb?p=preview)**

by the way, this is all within angular since you are using `ng-click` ... it is not an outside event